# How to smooth/fillet a shape imported from SVG

Tags: artifacts

I'm trying to import a SVG shape and smooth it out to be 3D printed as a necklace pendant.

Import SVG > Solidify > Subdivision and i get weird results.

[image]

Similar problem with:
Import SVG > Solidify > Smooth

I also tried remap but could not get good results.

What's the best way to get around this problem without retracing it in blender?

[blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qhAi0CYeX5h7wcfrHWUc6iOvF3coBrR7/view?usp=sharing)

[SVG file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18-ryo-z6-TiGZCzbc5CBlg7To1Pe6LcV/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because of very narrow triangles going back-and-forth across the surface.

I might try using *Beautify Faces* if you are willing to convert it to mesh, but if you don’t want to do that, try the *Remesh* modifier with various settings.

Comment: I get reasonable results with remesh + subdivide, but on a little more complex shape. It get's to slow and blender would crash.

Comment: Ah. Hmm. Well, I’m kind of shocked that that’s too heavy for blender, which even more makes me think you should convert the SVG into mesh without any modifiers, and then go into edit mode and see what the vertices and edges look like.

Comment: remesh + subdivide worked on the texas example. But on the a more complex shape imported from svg it hangs before i can crank up remesh and subdivide high enough to get good results.(8 cores, 32GB). I did convert curve to mesh as a first step.

Comment: Beautify Faces did help a bit